# How to change font colour in Awesome CV template

Tags: fonts, color, templates, awesome-cv

I have used the `Awesome CV template` on Overleaf and some of the text is grey rather than black but I have no idea how to change this. The only thing I can see about font colour the the `.tex` file is:

```
% Colors for text
% Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color
% \definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
% \definecolor{text}{HTML}{333333}
% \definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{5D5D5D}
% \definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{999999}
```

But no idea what to do with this...

Comment: Those lines name colors, but only if you remove the percent at the front (that's what's meant by "uncommenting "). Somewhere else in the file the colors are used. Can't tell without a complete document, though.

Comment: Thanks for that.. this is the template I am using:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm#.WifFKGjys2w

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as Matthew Leingang wrote in a comment; in LaTeX the `%` symbol is meant for commenting, this means that anything after a `%` symbol will not have any effect on the final outcome of the document.

This is great for making comments (like above), removing commands, and debugging.

If you have a really big `align` or `aligned` environment that throws an error (something like missing `$`) It's often really hard to find where. You can then use `%` to remove certain lines and track down where the bug is.

In your case the colors do the following:

- awesome: This is the color of the first few letters in each major point.
- darktext: First line under every major point, also in lists
- text:Text not given another color, used both in Big ovelines, and the smallest points.
- graytext: This is used for minor highlights
- lighttext: Used for headers and the line under the name.

The colors are written in hex color format in RGB, meaning that Red holds a value from 00 to ff, so does green and so does blue.

Thus the following inserted in the template:

```
\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{FFFF00}%Yellow
%% Colors for text
\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{00FF00} %green
\definecolor{text}{HTML}{FF00FF} % pink
\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{FF0000} % red
\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{0000FF} %blue
```

Will produce:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I managed to change them all to black.

Comment: Wow, that looks definitely not awesome.  But I'm glad you answered the question!

Comment: I wasn't going for awesome, i was going for distinct colors to show what  each color did, and the easy to remember colors was right at hand XD. But I could properbly have chosen some nicer easy to remember colors, just by using 9 instead of F XD.

Comment: How to make all the head sections (e.g., Education) all red instead of highlighting just the first three letters?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the number of colored characters in the head section you have to go to line 154

`% Awesome section color \def\@sectioncolor #1{% \ifbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{{\color{awesome}#1}}{#1}% }`

you can for expample add `#2#3#4#5` etc... and it will color the characters 1,2,3,4,5th etc...

`% Awesome section color \def\@sectioncolor #1#2#3#4#5{% \ifbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{{\color{awesome}#1#2#3#4#5}}{#1#2#3#4#5}% }`

Hope it helps.