# How can I remove faded color from Awesome CV template

Tags: color, fontawesome, awesome-cv

I am using Awesome-CV template from this github (https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV). The text which is used for description of section is light gray. It is hard to see the grey text. I would like to make it easy to see. I tried changing colour but the shade is always light which is hard to see.

What I tried

1. I tried changing color using this ([How to change font colour in Awesome CV template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404841/how-to-change-font-colour-in-awesome-cv-template)) and was successful but the entries are always faded with the same shade which I choose, I am guessing there is some opacity applied.

I am not able to remove the fade on the components highlighted with red color. Can someone please help me remove the fade?

[image: Faded underlined by red and boxed]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you got some compileable example code that shows what you've tried? Edit the question and add the code there. For RGB colour definitions, if all three channels, red, green, blue are the same value, you will get a shade of gray. Special case is black (0,0,0), and white(either 1,1,1 or 255,255,255, depending on the colour model being used. CYMK colour model has `K` (amount of black) which could be affecting your case or not. Please post some example code, beginning with `\documentclass`  and ending with `\end{document}`. You can use some dummy text.

Comment: For pure red, with no green or blue contribution, use `{FF0000}`; green = `{00FF00}`; blue = `{0000FF}`; cyan = `{00FFFF}` = full green + full blue, etc. Notation is hexadecimal, from `00` to `FF`: `00` means `total off` for that channel, `01` = tiny bit on, `F0` = strongly on, `FF` = full on.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, It was a simple fix

```
\newcommand*{\footerfont}{\sourcesanspro}
\newcommand*{\bodyfont}{\sourcesanspro}
\newcommand*{\bodyfontlight}{\sourcesansprolight}
```

The `sourcesansprolight` was responsible for getting it light.

Comment: As usual here -- please show for a fast proof an compilable TeX code ...